# Sum values depending on other value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of objects that represent transactions of shares:

```
[{
    date : ...,
    symbol: 'TSLA',
    amount: 3,
    price: 1000.00
  },
{
    date : ...,
    symbol: 'AAPL',
    amount: 1,
    price: 1200.00
  },
{
    date : ...,
    symbol: 'AAPL',
    amount: 7,
    price: 1300.00
  }]
```

I need to get sum of amounts based of symbol of that array, so output would be:

```
[{
   symbol: 'TSLA',
    amount: 3,
},
{
  symbol: 'AAPL',
    amount: 8,
}]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this with build in operations in javascript, or is the only way to do it with 2 array and double loop?

I was thinking of saving symbols in separate Set, and then suming all amounts, but is there a better way?

I've tried this, but this seems to only copy the original array.

```
const checkIfExists = (array, value) => {
  array.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (el.symbol === value) {
      return i;
    }
  });
  return -1;
};

const calculateSameValues = (data) => {
  let result = [];

  data.forEach((el) => {
    const index = checkIfExists(result, el.symbol);
    if (index === -1) {
      result.push({symbol: el.symbol, amount: el.amount});
    } else result[index].amount += el.amount;
  });

  console.log(result);
};
```

Comment: why would you need a "double loop"? It seems obvious to me that you can do this in one pass through the array, either with a `for` loop or with a utility like `reduce`.

Comment: Well, the first loop is obviusly to loop all elements in given array, and other loop is to check if new array already includes that symbol, if it does, sum the values, and if not, create new element in new array.

Comment: oh I see, thanks. That is technically another loop, then - but unless you have hundreds of different symbols in your array it's not likely to be a noticeable performance hit.

Comment: Yes, loop through the array and create a new object to put the results.  By using a object you don't have to check if a key exists.  Just write the code to sum the values.  Like:  array.key += value;.  If the key doesn't exist it will be created.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've updated the question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my `checkIfExists` function was returning always -1.
I fixed it by saving index in seperate variable and than returning it.

Here's code:

```
const checkIfExists = (array, value) => {
  let index = -1;

  array.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (el.symbol === value) {
      console.log(i);
      index = i;
    }
  });
  return index;
};
```

Note that this still uses 2 loops, I was looking for something more efficient, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array.reduce() something like this:

```
const arr = [{
    symbol: 'TSLA',
    amount: 3,
    price: 1000.00
  },
{
    symbol: 'AAPL',
    amount: 1,
    price: 1200.00
  },
{
    symbol: 'AAPL',
    amount: 7,
    price: 1300.00
  }]

const x = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  const idx = acc.findIndex(el => el.symbol === cur.symbol);
  const obj = {
    symbol: cur.symbol,
    amount: cur.amount,
  }
  if(idx < 0) {
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    acc[idx].amount = acc[idx].amount + cur.amount;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(x);
```